# Is it more secure to run a desktop app within a applet?

Tags: java, security, applet, desktop

Fist of all, when I say "run a desktop app within a applet" I mean do a Applet application that runs off-line, instead of a Desktop application that runs inside a JFrame.

The little I know about applets (and maybe something I say is wrong, please correct me) is that applets have all permitions **not** granted by default. Also, the applets run inside a Sandbox, that does not allow information in or out without explicity permition.

So, if I am focused on security in my application, its best to run it inside an applet (off-line, for a desktop application) then inside a JFrame. Is it right?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The same applies to desktop applications deployed with Java Web Start. Except for that their development is a lot more fun and does not have all the nasty usability constraints of applets

The article [*Java Web Start and Security*](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/deployment/webstart/security.html) "describes the basics of security for applications deployed through Java Web Start." More details may be found in the article [*Deploying Software with JNLP and Java Web Start*](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/Programming/jnlp/).

Answer (score 0):

It's not quite correct to say that certain permissions are note granted by default; it's rather that applets have got a different SecurityContext.

But if you do not want to fiddle with that, go with Konrad's suggestion to run it as a Java Web Start Application.